# Как можно отфильтровать массив?

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, 7]];


console.log(result); //[1, 2, 5];
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать через `filter`:

```
let arr = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, 7]];
let result = arr.filter((item) => {
  return !Array.isArray(item);
})

console.log(result); //[1, 2, 5];
```

Comment: Главное, чтобы потом не сказали, что там могут быть ещё и строковые значения и объекты))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, тут вопрос вообще не точный, так что по догадкам - надо убрать массивы...

Comment: или оставить числа ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский бесконечные догадки. Какой вопрос - такой ответ)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, спасибо. так с строками работает ведь. данный код

Comment: @boss ты не уточнил в вопросе смысл "отфильтровать массив". А как? Что хочешь именно получить? Какие возможные варианты и так далее. Вот и началась тут демагогия)

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, 7]]

const result = arr.filter((el) => typeof el === 'number')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, 7]];
    
    
    const sortArray = arr => {
      const result = [];
      for (const item of arr) {
        if (item.length > 1) {
          continue;
        } else {
          result.push(item);
        }
      }
    
      return result;
    }
    
    sortArray(arr);
```